# Would like to create excel file with 2 sheets inside then append dataFrame to sheet_1 or sheet_2

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas, dataframe

As in topic, would like to append datas from df to excel file to sheet ONE or TWO
Always i see only sheet 'TWO' in my file.

```
def create_report_file(self, df1, df2):
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(self._filename, engine='openpyxl')
    df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='ONE')
    df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='TWO')
    writer.save()
```

````
def save_to_excel(self, df, sheet_name):
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(self._filename, engine='openpyxl')
    if df == 1:
        self._df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name)
    else:
        self._df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name)
    writer.save()```
````

Comment: You want two sheets for two dfs, df1 to sheet1 and df2 to sheet2. But you are seeing only one sheet. Is that right?

Comment: yes thats right, append data row to sheet( 'ONE' or "TWO') and save - doesn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

This should work. Each dataframe will be written to two different sheet.

```
with pd.ExcelWriter("output.xlsx") as writer:  
    if condition: 
        df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='sheet1')
    else:
        df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='sheet2')
```

Comment: still same problem exists, should we create excel file before, or use writer.save() and writer.close() after ???

Comment: Very odd. Works for me. With clause does not need any .close() explicitly. Could it happen only one condition is getting executed and because of that it writes only one dataframe to one sheet?

Comment: for me it's odd too, I'm listing my df1 and df2 during script and it looks fine, rows are incrementing properly, i try to append each row to my excel, parallel *.csv file looks fine and correct.

Comment: adding one line to df and append to excel file to different sheets failed, solution was to collect all data to df and added to excel file at once.  
`writer = pd.ExcelWriter(f"{self._filename}.xlsx")`
`self._df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='All_measurements')`
`self._df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='AVERAGE')`
`writer.save()`